# Null pointer Exception - findViewById()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate, findviewbyid

Can anyone help me to find out what can be the issue with this program.
In the `onCreate()` method the `findViewById()` returns null for all ids and this causes a null pointer exception later. I can not figure out why the `findViewById()` can not find the view. Any suggestions?

This is the main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewPager pager;
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayout layout1, layout2, layout3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_View);
        layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_View);
        layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.third_View);

        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount() { 
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

            LinearLayout l = null;

            if (position == 0 )
            {
                l = layout1;
            }
            if (position == 1)
            {
                l = layout2;
            }

            if (position == 2)
            {
                l = layout3;
            }
                collection.addView(l, position);
                return l;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view==object);
        }

         @Override
         public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
                 collection.removeView((View) view);
         }
    }
}
```

And the related XML files:

activity_main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#a4c639">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:id="@+id/main_pager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_first layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/first_View">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_second layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/second_View">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity_third layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/third_View">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`findViewById()` returns a View if it exists in the layout you provided in `setContentView()`, otherwise it returns null and that's what happening to you. Note that if you don't `setContentView()`, and don't have a valid view to `findViewById()` on, `findViewById()` will always return null until you call `setContentView()`.

This also means variables in the top-level trigger an NPE, because they're called before `onCreate()`, and by extension, before `setContentView()`. See also [the activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Example if you `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);` and then call `findViewById(R.id.first_View);` it will return a View which is your layout.

But if you call `findViewById(R.id.second_View);` before `setContentView()`, it will return `null` since there is not a view in your `activity_first.xml` layout called `@+id/second_View`.

Comment: I have included all layouts to the main layout and I have no null pointer exception anymore. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: When I used this on a different view other than the currently displaying view, that one appeared. To get over with that unwanted behavior, I referred the view without using setContentView as follows. 
    
layout1 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.first_View, null);    
Then to access anything inside it, I could use     
Button botton = (Button) layout1.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Just adding so that it might be helpful to sombody.

Comment: Why? What is the advantage of forcing us?

Comment: Then what's the solution to include the resource which is not provided  in`setContentView()`.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

For those cases within an Activity class.

> `Activity.findViewById(int id)`
>
> Finds a view that was identified by the `id` attribute from **the XML that was processed in `onCreate(Bundle)`**.

---

Otherwise, such as an Fragment, Adapter, a `View` from a `LayoutInflater`, etc.

> `View.findViewById(int id)`
>
> Look for **a child view** with the given `id`. If this view has the given id, return this view.

---

Either case,

> **Returns**
> The view if found **or `null` otherwise**.

---

Now, re-check your XML files. Make sure you put the right value into `setContentView` or `inflater.inflate`.

In the case of an Activity, call `findViewById` after `setContentView`.

Then, make sure there is a View you are looking for with `android:id="@+id/..."` in that layout. Make sure the `+` is at `@+id`, which will add the resource to the `R.id` values to ensure you can find it from Java.

Answer (score 2):

The views you're trying to get are not defined in your `activity_main` layout. You need to programmatically inflate the views you're trying to add to the pager.-

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LinearLayout l = null;

    if (position == 0) {
        l = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_first, null);
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        l = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_second, null);
    }
    if (position == 2) {
        l = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_third, null);
    }

    collection.addView(l, position);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: How would you access the views in your mainactivity?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need clean your project in Eclipse (Project - Clean..).

Comment: that solved it for me - it's ridiculous that it's a manual step, and also that bugs compromise the id lookups. .
I thought machines are always logical - what on Earth can compromise the code in such a way?!

Answer (score 1):

add those views to the pager adapter before accessing them.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_View);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_View);
    layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.third_View);

}
```

in the pager adapter:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    if(position == 0){
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

        return layout;
    } 
    ... and so forth.

}
```

from here you can access them via findViewById.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a stupid mistake on my part. I had written code in the OnCreate method but it was **above** the `setContentView` line of code. Once I moved my code below this line the application started working fine.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Warlock said above is right , you should initial LinearLayout layout1, layout2, layout3 by the right way:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.first_View, null);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.second_View, null);
LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.third, null);
```

wish my advise help you

Answer (score 0):

In Android, `findViewById(R.id.some_id)` works when you are finding view in the layout set.

That is, if you have set a layout say:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

**Views can be found only in this layout (my_layout).**

In your code `layout1`, `layout2`, `layout3` all are three different layouts and they are not set to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

The `findViewById` method must find what is in the layout (which you called in the `setContentView`)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error today and it was so simple to clear, that I "facepalmed".

Just try to add the UI element to your layout xml File in your **res/layout-port directory!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Use the adaptor, to inflate the layout, and based on the position you can search for the view.

```
override fun instantiateItem(collection: ViewGroup, position: Int) : ViewGroup {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
    val layout = inflater.inflate(mData[position], collection, false) as ViewGroup

    if(position == your_position) {
       val nameOfField: TextView = layout.findViewById(R.id.item_id)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is also generated when you are having same name of many components in XML file. Even if they are different layout files you should give every element a unique name.
This error occur because you are having a XML element with the same name in another layout file and android studio is trying to access that and showing this error