# I am getting System.NullReferenceException when referencing a method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a button that when clicked should call a method. The program will build but I am getting a runtime error System.NullReferenceException when the method is being called. How is the method null? The exception occurs at the comment line.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            _countdown = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.countdown);

            Button buttonStop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.stopButton);
            //exception happens below
            buttonStop.Click +=  stopButton_Click;

            Button buttonSet = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.setButton);
            buttonSet.Click += setButton_Click;

            Button buttonClear = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.clearButton);
            buttonClear.Click += clearButton_Click;

            var back = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonBack);
            back.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(DM_App_Code_Fragment.MainScreen));
            };
...
        }
```

This is the method to be called.

```
private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopTimer();
}

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }
```

This is the code related to _timer

```
    //initialization
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

The below code occurs in OnCreate method.

```
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        _timer.Enabled = false;
```

Also this is a group effort with two Resource.Designer.cs files. There are two of these in the files: One in Resource.Designer.cs and the other in Resource.DesignerQT.cs so I commented out one of them because I was getting an error Duplicate "global::Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute" attribute. Now I think this is why the button is null because the Resource files are not loading properly. Is there a way to have two Resource.Designer.cs files in a project or is only one allowed?

```
[assembly:global::Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute("QuickTimer.Resource",   
IsApplication=true)]
```

This is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Quick Timer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewQuickTimer" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Hour"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewQuickTimer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/textViewHours" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Min"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewHours"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewHours"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewMinutes" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Sec"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSeconds" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewHours"
        android:prompt="@string/hours"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerHours" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewMinutes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:prompt="@string/minutes"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMinutes" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewSeconds"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:prompt="@string/seconds"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSeconds" />
    <Button
        Click="setButton_Click"
        android:text="Set Timer / Start"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinnerMinutes"
        android:id="@+id/setButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Timer Countdown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/setButton"
        android:id="@+id/countdown" />
    <Button
        Click="stopButton_Click"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        Click="clearButton_Click"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdown"
        android:id="@+id/clearButton" />
    <Button
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/clearButton"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBack" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is `StopTimer()`?

Comment: Is the `buttonStop` variable `null`?

Comment: I just debugged and found the variable to be null indeed. Should I use this to create it? Button buttonStop = new Button(this)

Comment: No you should not (and if you do, you have to attach it to the layout). Post your layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is one more space than intended before the method name.

Plus, you may inline the **StopTimer** method.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling FindViewById too early, this is why it returns a null reference. (Wait until onFinishInflate() is completed)

For a similar SO issue please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/android-null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid)

Comment: How do I know onFinishInflate() is completed? When to call FindViewById?

Comment: Please look at : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null