# Unfortunately Stopped , Error when Call Adapter using Fragment (i Think)

Tags: java, android

no error log when im try run application, but when im open MovieFragment my apps unfortunately close idk whats the problem, but i think is problem with my adapter, please someone help me

btw im newbie using fragment bc its more easier

MovieFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;


import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieFragment extends Fragment{
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MovieFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://...../json.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public MovieFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("images1"));
                                //movie.setDescribe(obj.getString("describe"));
                                //movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                //        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id"));
                                movie.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));

                                /*// Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

CustomeListAdapter.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView describe = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.describe);
        TextView tipe = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipe);
        // TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        // TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        //describe
        // describe.setText(m.getDescribe());

        //tipe
        tipe.setText(m.getTipe());

        // rating
        //rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        // String genreStr = "";
        // for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        //    genreStr += str + ", ";
        //}
        //genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
        //        genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        // genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

log error

```
    04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.felix.tgpfg, PID: 17482
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.felix.tgpfg.MovieFragment.onCreateView(MovieFragment.java:71)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 15:40:26.543 17482-17482/com.felix.tgpfg E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Blackbelt its not the same, please some once help :)

Comment: it is never the same. Which one is line 71 on MovieFragment.java ?

Comment: @Blackbelt here : listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: listView is null. Did you have it in `fragment_home.xml`?

Comment: @Blackbelt of course i have 5 fragment, home, friends,message (3 all example), calculator, and this movie

Comment: @F_X No, that is not what was asked. The question was is there a `+@id/list` inside the `fragment_home.xml`

Comment: @Blackbelt [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/android-null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid) is more closely a duplicate

Comment: @Blackbelt oh damn, sorry for that, i put the wrong layout :), and now is fine thanks for your help