# New Activity crashes on startup

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When clicking a Button to switch from the main Activity to my "ColoursGame" Activity the app crashes.

I'm still a beginner so not an expert at debugging.

**The main activity code**

```
Button colorsGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colours);
            colorsGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColoursGame.class));
                }
            });
```

**Manifest new activity**

```
<activity android:name=".ColoursGame"
        android:label="ColourGame"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

**ColoursGame Activity OnCreate code**

```
public class ColoursGame extends Activity {

int livesCount = 3;
String x;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_colours_game);

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startColors);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vSwitch.showNext();
            x = String.valueOf(livesCount);
            lives.setText(x);
            text();
            textColor();
            backgroundColor();

            start();
        }
    });

}
```

**The Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.aynaar.numbersgameforkids, PID: 3278
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aynaar.numbersgameforkids/com.aynaar.numbersgameforkids.ColoursGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2323)
                  at com.aynaar.numbersgameforkids.ColoursGame.<init>(ColoursGame.java:42)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: `Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startColors);` Error is caused by this statement. Make sure your layout has a button with `startColors` id.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `Button` named **colours** in your layout ?

Comment: show your layout from both activities

Comment: all the ids are correct I can't seem to add an XML file its struggling with indentation

Answer (score 1):

> `at com.aynaar.numbersgameforkids.ColoursGame.<init>(ColoursGame.java:42)`

Don't call `findViewById` outside of `onCreate`, there's no Window to call `findViewById` at that point.

---

If you still get a NullPointer, then you must have `@+id/startColors` in `activity_colours_game.xml`

[Answer explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538562/2308683)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startColors);
```

According to the error you are trying to reach a button that doesnt exist in your activity layout file (whatever it is). Check the id of your button and make sure it is placed on the layout page that related with your "ColoursGame" Activity.

Comment: No. `Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`... The Window is null. Not the button