# I'm new to android studio and am getting this error that I don't know how to fix

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, new-operator

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.madera/com.example.madera.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

```
This is my code Login.java
package com.example.madera;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mLoginBtn;
    TextView mCreateBtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);

        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email is Required.");
                    return;

                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Password is Required.");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length()<6){
                    mPassword.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Character");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate the user

                fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Error !"+ task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Registration.class));

            }
        });
    }
}

this is login xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.092" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="New? Create Account"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginBtn" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This are the files ehre the error is according to the debugger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null pointer Exception - findViewById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid)

Answer (score 1):

You have not set a view like this in the XML:

`<Button android:id="@+id/createText" //`

`..... // the rest of the information />`

for the "mCreateBtn" so it is returning null.

apologies for the format of the response. I'm still not accustomed to stackoverflow.