# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)

Tags: android

ERROR
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.henvelt_joseph, PID: 4817
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.henvelt_joseph/com.example.henvelt_joseph.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.henvelt_joseph.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        //Create the buttons
        Button MSButton, DeptButton, SpecButton, GGButton, GCButton, ISButton, GDButton,WFUBUtton,CUButton, CartButton;
    
        //Create a Dummy String for sections of the app that are under construction
        private final String DUMMYMESSAGE = "This Section of the App is under construction";
    
        /**
         * onCreate will create the buttons when the app is first started or when the homescreen is visted
         * @param savedInstanceState
         */
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            //Have the buttons find their IDs
           MSButton = findViewById(R.id.MobileShopping);
           DeptButton = findViewById(R.id.Departments);
            SpecButton = findViewById(R.id.Specials);
            GGButton = findViewById(R.id.GiftGuide);
            GCButton = findViewById(R.id.GiftCards);
            ISButton = findViewById(R.id.InventorySystem);
            GDButton = findViewById(R.id.GetDirections);
            WFUBUtton = findViewById(R.id.WorkForUs);
            CUButton = findViewById(R.id.ContactUs);
            CartButton = findViewById(R.id.CartMain);
    
    
            //Go to the specials section to display items that are on sale and coupons
            //In this section the user can add items to their carts
            SpecButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * onClick will bring the user to the special section of the app
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent Specials = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Specials.class);
                    startActivity(Specials);
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            MSButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy setOnClickListenerMESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            DeptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            GGButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            GCButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            ISButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            GDButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            WFUBUtton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Display a dummy MESSAGE for the section of the app that is not support.
            CUButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will display a message informing the user that this section of the app is under construction
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), DUMMYMESSAGE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Allow the user to go to the cart from the home screen
            CartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                /**
                 * Will bring the user to the shopping cart
                 * @param view
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent Specials = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShoppingCart.class);
                    startActivity(Specials);
    
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    
        public void setContentView(int activity_main) {
        }
    }
    
     <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/MobileShopping"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Mobile_Shopping" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Departments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Departments" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Specials"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Specials" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/GiftGuide"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Gift_Guide" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/GiftCards"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Gift_Cards" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/InventorySystem"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Inventory_System" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/GetDirections"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Get_Directions" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/WorkForUs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Work_For_Us" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ContactUs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/ContactUs" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/CartMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                    android:text="@string/Cart" />
    
            </LinearLayout>`enter code here`
        </ScrollView>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_home"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Home" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error trace says the problem is caused by line 52 in `MainActivity`.
Please check it out which button you are setting `OnClickListener` in line 52 and make sure you have initialized that button referencing the correct id in the XML.
The error means, your either have not initialized that button or initialized it with id with incorrect XML file.

If you are dealing with multiple fragments and XML files, then it is worth to double check layout file names being referenced from the code. In your code, you are referencing 'R.id.activity_main' for the `MainActivity` layout. It doesn't harm checking the name of XML file that contains all those buttons, is `activity_main.xml` and it resides in res/layout folder.

This topic is discussed hundreds of time even thousands.
Here are some links to learn more.

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

[Null pointer Exception - findViewById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid)